# Button Click and LinkButton Click

Tags: asp.net

I am having a strange day! I am trying to access values inside the Datagrid control. There are textboxes in each row of the Datagrid control. If I use a asp.net button control outside the datagrid control I can access all the values. But if I use LinkButton outside the datagrid control then I cannot access any value.

I have to use LinkButton.

UPDATE 1: Code

```
 //This works 
         Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                    Dim indexes() As Integer = dgReceipts.SelectedIndexNumbers
                End Sub

        //This does not work and I get 0 items in the SelectedIndexNumbers
                Protected Sub LinkButtonUpdateReceipts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonUpdateReceipts.Click
                    Dim indexes() As Integer = dgReceipts.SelectedIndexNumbers
                End Sub

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
             <c1:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUpdateReceipts" runat="server" Text="Update Totals" Icon="images/go-blue-right.gif"></c1:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised that either of those work.  You do not appear to have an OnClick event for either of those buttons.  At a minimum I would add an OnClick event to your LinkButton that fires `LinkButtonUpdateReceipts_Click`.

Also, why aren't you just using `<asp:LinkButton`? what is `<c1:LinkButton`?

Comment: c1 is nothing! Just think I am using asp linkbutton. The weird thing is that when I click the linkbutton the event is handles correctly by the linkbutton controls.

Comment: So the event IS firing for the LinkButton?